# Do Python sets change order only on start of programme execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am just starting to learn Python and programming at all, so probably a stupid question, but I can't stop wondering: when do sets actually change the order of their parts.

So I tried to check.

I have decided to try it out and wrote up a set and some print commands. I actually expected that each time it prints out there will be new order.
But no.
Order seems to change only when I execute code. Tried in replit.com and in PyCharm IDE. I have even included print(type()) command to check that I actually did created a set, not something else (being a newbie and all..).

So the question: when do Python sets actually change the order of their parts?

Here is my code:

```
mixed_set = {1, "1", "alef", "bet", "gimel", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "delta", "gelato", "London", "Paris", '222', 0.48, "-67", 12113, "Berlin", "Volperting", "August", "Seneca", "Tiberivs"}
print('\ncheck the class of mixed_set: ', type(mixed_set))
print('\ncheck the length of mixed_set: ', len(mixed_set), "\n")
print("first print: ", mixed_set) # first print
print("second print: ", mixed_set) # second print
print("third print: ", mixed_set) # third print
print("fourth print: ", mixed_set) # fourth print
print("fifth print:", mixed_set) # fifth print

print('\n Lets run a print over a for cycle\n')
for x in range(5):
    print(mixed_set)

print('\nNow lets run a print over a while cycle\n')
counter = 0
while counter < 6:
    print(f"this is while cycle print number {counter}", mixed_set)
    counter += 1

print('\nNow lets command print by function\n')


def print_a_set_five_times(set_name):
    print("first print from function", set_name)
    print("second print from function", set_name)
    print("third print from function", set_name)
    print("fourth print from function", set_name)
    print("fifth print from function", set_name)


print_a_set_five_times(mixed_set)

print('\nNow lets command print by player input 5 times over for cycle\n')

for i in range (5):
    a = input("Enter y to print the set: ")
    if a == "y":
        print("printed by command", mixed_set)
```

And here is what I got as results. Order is the same throughout the single run (copypaste from PyCharm):

```
check the class of mixed_set:  <class 'set'>

check the length of mixed_set:  21 

first print:  {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
second print:  {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
third print:  {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
fourth print:  {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
fifth print: {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}

 Lets run a print over a for cycle

{0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
{0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
{0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
{0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
{0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}

Now lets run a print over a while cycle

this is while cycle print number 0 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
this is while cycle print number 1 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
this is while cycle print number 2 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
this is while cycle print number 3 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
this is while cycle print number 4 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
this is while cycle print number 5 {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}

Now lets command print by function

first print from function {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
second print from function {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
third print from function {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
fourth print from function {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
fifth print from function {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}

Now lets command print by player input 5 times over for cycle

Enter y to print the set: y
printed by command {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
Enter y to print the set: y
printed by command {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
Enter y to print the set: y
printed by command {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
Enter y to print the set: y
printed by command {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}
Enter y to print the set: y
printed by command {0.48, 1, '-67', 'London', 'August', '1', 12113, 'delta', 'Paris', 'alef', 'Tiberivs', 'gelato', '222', 'bet', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'gimel', 'alpha', 'gamma', 'Volperting', 'beta'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'm unclear about your expectations vs results of your code. Your printouts seem to indicate no change in the order, but you say: `"Order seems to change"`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in English (not my mother tongue).
So:
what I expected: order to change at each new command executed on a set. I.e. I thought that if I do 2 print commands one after another I will get different orders in printouts.
what I got: order changes only on program launch. So if program has 2 print commands, order on print command 1 and print command 2 will be the same. Order changes only when I launch the *whole program* one more time

Comment: Ok, so are you saying that if *I* run your code it is unlikely that I will see the same output as your sample above?

Comment: i think it can change order when you create set, and add or remove some element in set, When you don't change content then it doesn't have to make any changes in memory so it doesn't change order.

Comment: and there is no rule where it will put new element. If I create `{0.5}` and `add(0)` then I get `{0.5, 0}`, and if I create `{0}` and add `{0.5}` then I get `{0, 0.5}` - so it seems it add at the end, but if I create `{1}` and `add(0)` then I get `{0, 1}` so it doesn't put it at the end. And it can behave different on your computer - I created set from your code and I get it in different order - I have `"222"` before `12113` but you have `12113` much before `"222"`

Comment: @quamrana - please run it and post your results here.
If my observations are correct - there will be same order within single run of code, but order will change every time you re-run the code from start.

Comment: @furas THB sets with only numbers seem to be even more baffling.
I have run this code:
```
nums_set = {1, -9, 2131, 2, 2.0, 2.0, 2, 8979, 82, -1, 0.5, -2, 12, 0, 0.0001, -0.003, 6, 7, 9, 3, 2, 1.4, 1.5}
print("first print: ", nums_set)
print("second print: ", nums_set) 
print("third print: ", nums_set) 
```
and got exactly same output not only within a run, but from run to run of code:
{0.5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1.4, -0.003, 6, 7, 9, 1.5, 12, 82, 8979, 2131, 0.0001, -2, -9, -1}

Tried 10x on replit & 10x in PyCharm - got the same printouts 20 times. Please run and post results.

Comment: Yes, I just ran your code five times in a row and *inside* each run the set printed the same but every different run produced output different to other runs. eg. the last item printed was different, but also I noted that the first two items were very often: `{0.48, 1, ...` just like your sample above.

Comment: you create set only once at start- and printing doesn't change content in set so it can't display it in different order. Set may have some inner rules how to organize data in memory and on the same computer with the same data (create with the same way) it may create the same order but I used your code on my computer and I got different order. And when I add items in different order then I can get set with different order. And I don't know if what order I will get. And some calculation can depends on order in set and you give code to someone else then it may get different results.

Comment: set from question: Python3.10: `{0.48, 1, 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'delta', 12113, 'Paris', 'Tiberivs', '-67', 'alef', 'alpha', '222', 'gamma', 'Volperting',
 'gelato', 'London', 'bet', 'beta', 'gimel', '1', 'August'}`. Python3.8 `{0.48, 1, '222', 'Seneca', 'beta', 'alpha', '1', 'gamma', 'August', 'Berlin', 'Volperting', 'alef', 'bet', 'gelato', 'Paris', 'London', 12113, 'gimel', 'delta', '-67', 'Tiberivs'}`, bpython `{0.48, 1, 'Volperting', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', '222', 'gamma', 'delta', 12113, '-67', 'Tiberivs', 'Paris', 'alpha', 'August', 'gelato', 'bet', '1', 'beta', 'gimel', 'alef', 'London'}`

Comment: @Yougoworkhuman are you looking for answers for the C-Python implementation of Python? If you're asking about Python 3 in general, the answer is rather simple: Sets are unordered and in which order items are read and displayed depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Yougoworkhuman for using Python all you need to know is: The order of items in a set is about as reliable as the order of items in a bag.

Answer (score 0):

I think `set` may change order only when you modify content in `set` - when you create `set`, add new item to `set`, etc. (when it has to find place for new element(s)). But rather not when you remove item from `set`.

`print()` doesn't change content in `set` so every `print` will display the same order.

You create `set` only once - at start - and later you use different methods to display it.
But this doesn't change content in `set`.

Because you use the same computer, the same Python, and the same code - so you may always get the same results.

---

But when I run the same code

```
mixed_set = {1, "1", "alef", "bet", "gimel", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "delta", "gelato", "London", "Paris", '222', 0.48, "-67", 12113, "Berlin", "Volperting", "August", "Seneca", "Tiberivs"}
print(mixed_set)
```

with different Pythons then I get different orders

Python 3.10:

```
{0.48, 1, 'Berlin', 'Seneca', 'delta', 12113, 'Paris', 'Tiberivs', '-67', 'alef', 'alpha', '222', 'gamma', 'Volperting',  'gelato', 'London', 'bet', 'beta', 'gimel', '1', 'August'}
```

Python 3.8

```
{0.48, 1, '222', 'Seneca', 'beta', 'alpha', '1', 'gamma', 'August', 'Berlin', 'Volperting', 'alef', 'bet', 'gelato', 'Paris', 'London', 12113, 'gimel', 'delta', '-67', 'Tiberivs'}
```

bpython (on Python 3.10)

```
{0.48, 1, 'Volperting', 'Berlin', 'Seneca', '222', 'gamma', 'delta', 12113, '-67', 'Tiberivs', 'Paris', 'alpha', 'August', 'gelato', 'bet', '1', 'beta', 'gimel', 'alef', 'London'}
```

IDE `Thonny` (with Python 3.10)

```
{0.48, 1, 'alef', '1', 'gamma', 'Tiberivs', 'London', 'Seneca', 12113, 'delta', 'beta', 'Volperting', 'alpha', 'bet', 'August', 'gelato', '-67', '222', 'Berlin', 'Paris', 'gimel'}
```

And the same tools on your computer may give different orders.

---

**EDIT:**

After more tests I see I get different order even if I run the same code again with the same Python.
I run it on Linux.

---

And when I create `set` in different ways then sometimes I get different orders.

```
a = set({0.5})
a.add(0)
print(a)

b = set({0})
b.add(0.5)
print(b)
```

gives me

```
{0.5, 0}
{0, 0.5}
```

But the same code for values `0`, `1` gives me always the same result `{0, 1}`.